# How does stratified sampling work?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, estimation

I don't understand stratified sampling as it is described on [these slides on p. 4](https://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/gilesm/mc/mc/lec4.pdf). They consider a simple example of $$\int_{[0,\:1)}f\:{\rm d}\lambda,$$ where $\lambda$ denotes the Lebesgue measure on $\mathcal B(\mathbb R)$. Now they divide $I=[0,1)$ into strata. Say (, more generally than in the paper,) $$I=\biguplus_{j=1}^mI_j.$$ Now they take $n_j$ (although slightly more general) samples $U_{ij}$ from the uniform distribution $\mathcal U_{I_j}$ on $I_j$ and consider $$F_j:=\frac1{n_j}\sum_{i=1}^{n_j}f(U_{ij}$$ which almost surely tends to $\int_{I_j}f\:{\rm d}\lambda$ as $n_j\to\infty$. So, the estimator of $\int_If\:{\rm d}\lambda$ should be $$F:=\sum_{j=1}^mF_j.$$ However, they divide the sum on the right-hand side by the number of strata $m$. But why? This would only be correct if all the $F_j$ would be estimators for the same quantity (here $\int_If\:{\rm d}\lambda$) or am I missing something?

Comment: Do not delete a question immediately after receiving an answer.  This is disrespectful to the person who took the time to answer your question, and to anyone else who might find that answer useful in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because
$$
F_j = \frac{1}{n_j}\sum_{i=1}^{n_j} f(U_{ij})
$$
tends to
$$
F_j \to \frac{1}{|I_j|}\int_{I_j} f \,\mathrm{d}\lambda
$$
as $n_j \to \infty$. Indeed, the density of a uniform r.v. on $I_j$ is equal to $|I_j|^{-1}\mathbb{I}_{I_j}(x)$. For $m$ strata of equal length you have $|I_j|=1/m$ so that
$$
F_j \to m\int_{I_j}f \,\mathrm{d}\lambda.
$$
Reassembling the estimator over the whole interval $I=(0,1)$, you obtain
$$
\sum_{j=1}^m F_j\to m \int_I f \, \mathrm{d}\lambda.
$$
Hence the division by $m$ in the overall estimator.